# Why does this expression come out to 4 in C?

Tags: c

So this expression comes out to 4:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}, i= 3, b,c,d;
int *p = &i, *q = a; 
char *format = "\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d";
printf("%ld",(long unsigned)(q+1) - (long unsigned)q);
```

I have to explain it in my homework and I have no idea why it's coming out to that value. I see `(long unsigned)` casting `q+1`, and then we subtract the value of whatever `q` is pointing at as a `long unsigned` and I assumed we would be left with 1. Why is this not the case?

Comment: What is the type of `q`?

Comment: The proper format specifier for `unsigned long` is `%ul`.  Some implementations will happen to pass `unsigned long` to `printf` the same way as `int`, but such behavior is far from universal.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Using `%d` to print `long unsigned` is undefined behavior.  Absolutely nothing can be said about the output.  If that's not the only acceptable answer, whoever wrote the question has no business actually teaching C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think it is fine as long as the value within the range of `int`?

Comment: Sorry haha, I added the relevant code. q is a pointer pointing at an integer array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "Appears to work" is one possible outcome from undefined behavior.  But if whoever wrote this question does not understand that the code in question invokes undefined behavior, than I'll stand by my assertion that they should not be teaching C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I mean that conversion of unsigned long to `int` is well defined as long as the value is fitting. Or I am missing some piece here...Ah, right, the parameter won't get converted to `int`, it will stay `unsigned long`

Comment: The value of what q is pointing at is completely irrelevant.

Comment: The printing "works" in this case because most implementations that most people will come across (i.e. Windows/MSVC or Linux/gcc on x86) pass all integer types on the stack and use little endian byte ordering, so the first 4 bytes on the stack are the same as if an `int` was passed.  And because there are no other arguments, there is nothing to get messed up after that.

Comment: @dbush But if `long` is 64 bits (as it is in most non-Windows 64-bit implementations), pushing 8 bytes onto the stack when the format specifier indicates that 4 bytes were pushed is going to break things.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not if that argument was the last one and therefore the thing pushed on the stack.  Then then the last 4 bytes will never be read.

Comment: @dbush But that is an assumption that 8-byte arguments are passed by the same mechanism used to pass 4-byte arguments in a way that the first four bytes of the 8-byte argument are located exactly were the 4-byte argument would be. That's a rather long chain of assumptions. Arguments don't have to be passed by pushing onto a stack.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And I stated that assumption (Windows/MSVC or Linux/gcc on x86) explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `q` is a pointer the expression `q+1` employs *pointer arithmetic*.  This means that `q+1` points to one *element* after `q`, not one *byte* after `q`.

The type of `q` is `int *`, meaning it points to an `int`.  The size of an `int` on your platform is most likely 4 bytes, so adding 1 to a `int *` actually adds 4 to the raw pointer value so that it points to the next `int` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the parts of the expression and it becomes a bit clearer what is going on.

```
printf("%p\n",(q+1));
printf("%p\n",q);
printf("%ld\n",(long unsigned)(q+1));
printf("%ld\n",(long unsigned)q);
```

It becomes more clear that q is a pointer pointing to the zeroth element of a, and q+1 is a pointer pointing to the next element of a.  Int's are 4 bytes on my machine (and presumably on your machine), so they are four bytes apart.  Casting the pointers to unsigned values has no effect on my machine, so printing out the difference between the two gives a value of 4.

```
0x7fff70c3d1a4
0x7fff70c3d1a0
140735085269412
140735085269408
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because sizeof(int) is 4.

This is an esoteric corner of C that is usually best avoided.

(If it doesn't make sense yet, add some temporary variables).

BTW, the printf format string is incorrect.  But that's not why it's outputting 4.

Comment: This would be improved by clarifying that it's printing `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int)` happens to be 4 *on that particular compiler*. (I'd also dispute that basic pointer arithmetic is an esoteric corner, but that's more of an opinion.)

Comment: Yeah the problem is a Human Compiler problem, so  I didn't write this code and would never write code like this haha. It's deliberately confusing code. (Also, I hate problems like this.) It's just testing our understanding of data types in C.